# How use GPS almanac information?

Tags: gps

I need use the data of this site: http://www.navcen.uscg.gov/?Do=gpsArchives&path=2012
to develop a small software that plot a chart about satellate availability, something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0iGL.jpg

The user must set a day, a latitude/longitude position and a time zone, then my application must plot the satellate availability for 7 days (from user day) to choose the best day.

I'm not a GPS expert so I don't know which and how use the data from almanac to make the plot.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're good at Matlab you could [try using this](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36355-gps-satellites-visibility-prediction-by-exerting-google-earth-terrain)

> This program calculate GPS visible satellites by exerting terrain for high accuracy prediction.
>
> inputs:
>
> 1. Coordinate of Station on earth.
> 2. GPS Almanac file.
> 3. Terrain Data in "txt" format(just for DSM calculation).

---

Or you could go through the [gpstk code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gpstk/files/) and refer to how [ComputeStationSatelliteVisibility](http://www.gpstk.org/bin/view/Documentation/ComputeStationSatelliteVisibilityManua)  l is implemented

Answer (score 0):

The almanac contains the elipse parameters that describe the curve of one satellite around the earth. Using these params you could determine where the sats are positioned for a specific time and position.

Assume a visibility of 170° of the sky: 5° are hidden by houses or mountains at the horizon.

Refer to :

http://www.navcen.uscg.gov/?pageName=gpsAlmanacs

and

http://www.navcen.uscg.gov/pdf/gps/Programmatically%20Accessing.pdf